# How to hide address bar in puppeteer (with headless false)

Tags: puppeteer

I want to launch Chromium with headless false and hide the address bar (and others like menus, tools, etc)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    console.log('launching');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com');
    await page.setViewport({width:400, height:300});
    await page.keyboard.press('F11'); //doesn't work and it is'n exact I want
})();
```

I get:

[image: I get]

I want:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi there you can pass any chromium flags through agrs in the options object at `browser.lunch(options)`. You are looking for `--kiosk` or `--app`

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--app']});
```

The only detail is that kiosk mode will set the window on fullscreen. That may mess with your viewport size and leave a gray area. 
Here are the docs, and a list of every flag available

- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions
- https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Actually you should use `--app`, instead of `--disable-infobars `

Comment: Your suggestion looks right @Enijar. The `--disable-infobars` is no longer available as a flag in chromium anymore. I'll update the answer.